# undefined array counting words: object

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, counting

So i am having issues coming up with an undefined array element.
1) cant get my undefined array to work
2) i want it to output the array as an occurrence of the word and number of times.

```
var wordCount =[];
splitAT.sort();
alert(splitAT);

for (var i = 0; i < splitAT.length; i++)
{
    if(splitAT[i] in wordCount)
{
wordCount.push(1);
}
else
{
wordCount[splitAT[i]] = 1;
}


document.write('[' + splitAT[i] + '][' + wordCount[i] + ']<br>') 
alert("your next wordcount is");
alert(wordCount); // this is just so i know where i am in the program.
alert("END");
```

Comment: You declared `wordCount` then use `splitAT`?

Comment: spliAT at is the string that was spliat in an array at the start of the code. full code not working in JSfiddle but here you are http://jsfiddle.net/fVGSN/ don't know why i am getting marked down -1 for this post but just trying to understand here. thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, use the right tool for the job: `wordCount` should be an object rather than an array:

```
var wordCount = {};  // note, curly brackets
```

...because you plan to access it using strings as keys, not numeric array indices. (Yes, an array will *work* for this purpose, but it's not an array's intended purpose.)

Then in your loop, if the current word is already in `wordCount` you want to add 1 to the existing value, not use `.push(1)` which will insert a new array element at the end of the numerically indexed elements.

```
// WRONG:
wordCount.push(1);           // inserts a new element
// RIGHT:
wordCount[splitAT[i]]++;     // increments the current value
```

Putting that together, you would count the words like this:

```
var wordCount = {};
splitAT.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < splitAT.length; i++) {
    if(splitAT[i] in wordCount) {
        wordCount[splitAT[i]]++;
    } else {
        wordCount[splitAT[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

> *"i want it to output the array as an occurrence of the word and number of times."*

To output the results you could do something like this:

```
var output = [];
for (var k in wordCount)
    output.push("'" + k + "' appears " + wordCount[k] + " time(s).");
document.getElementById("NumCount").value = output.join("\n");
```

(Assuming you want to output to a textarea element with `id="NumCount"`, which is what you had in your fiddle.)

Comment: This is really clear for me. Thank you all of my 9 rep is yours ;). I use alert for my debug tool. been working on this all day. Thanks you for explaining this to me.